# Sakuli Test sometimes gives 503 (Service temporarily unavailable) error

Tags: javascript, sahi

Test result is in OK status but this error appears on the screen .Can someone help what needs to be cheked?

Error : Error in testcase Form-test

> Cannot find Element within 3000ms by query:
> Locator: By(css selector, span)
> identifier: Jetzt anfordern
> relations:
> Wait timed out after 3119ms
> TimeoutError: Cannot find Element within 3000ms by query:
> Locator: By(css selector, span)
> identifier: Jetzt anfordern
> relations:
> Wait timed out after 3119ms
> at /headless/sakuli/sakuli-v2.3.0/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:841:17

[image]

Comment: Please add the full error message in text form as well so that it's searchable for future readers. [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3082296).

Answer (score 0):

"Service temp. unavailable" is usually thrown by a server, and means there is an issue with the server serving the request. Also see [503](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/503#:%7E:text=Der%20HTTP%2DStatuscode%20503%20Service,oder%20dass%20er%20%C3%BCberlastet%20ist.).

So in my opinion, this has nothing to do with Sakuli. With this server error, sakuli doesn´t find your identifier "Jetzt anfordern" as it clearly is not there. Test should be red and you should be informed about this server issue.

Unless I did not understood your question.. In this case, please describe in more detail what is happening.